# jQuery & livequery - check if a function has been attached to a element

Tags: jquery, livequery

I'm running this:

```
$("*:not(#boo) .content").livequery(function(){  
  $("input, select").blah();
});
```

`blah()` looks like this:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.blah = function(){
    var that = this;
    return this.each(function(){
       $(this).bind('change', function(){
           // do some stuff here

           return true;
        }).change();

   });
 };

})(jQuery);
```

and the html looks like:

```
<div id="boo">
 <div class="content">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  ...
 </div>
</div>

<div class="content">    
 <input type="text" />
 <input type="text" />
</div>
...
```

so what I'm trying to do is to attach that function & event to every input element that is not inside `#boo`.
This works, but the problem is that is doing it like every second over and over again and the browser freezes.

I need livequery because the html gets updated sometimes, and I need to attach the event again to new elements.

So how can I check if `blah()` has already been applied to a input element and stop there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query `$.data( object, 'events' )` you get an object back with properties of the events attached to it.  So in your case you could add this conditional:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.blah = function(){
    var that = this;
    return this.each(function(){
       if ($.data( $(this).get(0), 'events' ) !== void(0) &&
           $.data( $(this).get(0), 'events' ).change === void(0)) {
           $(this).bind('change', function(){
               // do some stuff here
               return true;
           }).change();
       }
   });
 };
})(jQuery);
```

...in order to only bind the function if it hasn't been already.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do it that way to be honest. Your first statement is a big NoNo, by querying for every single node in your markup and THEN exluding the elements you need. Why not doing it like this:

```
$('input').filter(function() { return !!$(this).closest('#boo').length } )
          .live('change', function() {
              // do some stuff here
          }).change();
```

This of course only makes sense, if there isn't anything more to do which is out of my scope here. But it really looks like you don't even need the `.livequery` here.

**Update**

The above code couldn't work. But this should do it:

```
$('input').live('change', function() {
    if(!$(this).closest('#boo').length) {
        // do some stuff here
    }
}).change();
```

Comment: Since she wants only those not in #boo, I think there should only be only one `!` in your filter function... anyway, +1